# Declaring CSS properties to display images across multiple screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I am using media queries to adjust the size of images according to the screen size they will be displayed at. I am creating 5 breakpoints.

Here is a [link](https://battlegriffin.github.io/CADUCEUS/yourbizz1.html) to what I have created so far, and here is a [link](https://github.com/Battlegriffin/a) to the repository of the files for the project.

I'm using Google Chrome DevTools to check how the project looks.
Everything runs well on desktop, iPad Pro, and all phone screens as you can see here:

[iPad Pro display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BwQP.jpg)
[Pixel 2 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw6ec.jpg)

But one of the iPad options does not get rendered properly when I use media queries. Here is the anomaly: the image is not sized property and gets stretched.
[iPad display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkLr2.jpg)

If I fix the iPad, the media query for iPad Pro becomes unresponsive and gets automatically displayed too wide. If I fix the iPad Pro, then the iPad one becomes unresponsive and gets displayed too wide or not at all.

I am using Visual Studio Code and there I have created three CSS files: index.html along with main.css, main1.css and main2.css.

To do that with the image, this is my html code:

```
<img class="img" src="logo1.png"

alt="My business' website logo"/>

<img class="imagerkan" id="imagery" src="logo1.png"

alt="My business' website logo"/>
```

This is my CSS at main.css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 85.375rem) {
.img {
display: block;
margin-top: 7%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 29.875rem;
width: 31%;
border-radius: 1.25rem;
}

#imagery {
display: none;
}

.imagerkan {
display: none;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 64rem) {
.img {
display: block;
margin-top: 21%;
margin-left: 17%;
margin-right: auto;
height: 11.875rem;
width: 68%;
border-radius: 1.25rem;
}

#imagery {
display: none;
}

.imagerkan {
display: none;
}
}
```

However, when I get to this next part, everything crumbles for one of the iPads:

main1.css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64rem) and (max-width: 85.375rem) {

#imagery {
display: block;
margin-top: 14%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 29.875rem;
width: 61%;
border-radius: 1.25rem;
}

.img {
display: none;
}

.imagerkan {
display: none;
}
}
```

This produces my intended outcome on iPad Pro. 
But when I want to use another media query so my image displays correctly on iPad, the 768 x 1024 size, nothing I do works. I get the distorted image posted earlier.

The only reason I created an additional css file was because I was having the same problem with the iPad Pro version when I was including the media query for it in main.css. But when I created main1.css and placed my media query there for iPad Pro there, it worked.

At first I had the media query for iPad the 768 x 1024 size, in main1.css,
but thinking that just like having created main1.css for the iPad Pro
media query fixed the problem for it, I made main2.css for the iPad
media query. This time it did not work.

Here's main2.css.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 51.5rem) and (max-width: 64rem) {

(824PX , the largest of the 7 phone sizes) (1024PX)
.imagerkan {  
display: block;
margin-top: 14%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 29.875rem;
width: 5%;
border-radius: 1.25rem;
}

.img {
display: none;
}

#imagery {
display: none;
}
}
```

I tried changing the media query for all phones in main.css to max 51.5 rem but this did not fix the problem either. One of the iPad media queries becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Now that Anshu has kindly cleared up content and formatting of the question, I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Hello Constantin , I am very new to this forum and , with all due respect , as you can see I did make an effort to express myself as respectfully as possible , I have been coding for about three months and all of this is new to , but above everything , as attested in my question , my expression was friendly and constructive.

Comment: Thank you for voting to re-open

Comment: In the case that this doesn't reopen, I recommend against using `rem` for mediaquery sizes. Instead, use actual `px`. There are plenty of resources that provide good media queries, although you don't need many if you're a decent developer. [This is a bit too much, but gets the point across](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/)

Comment: @Battlegriffin thank you for including your existing work and code! For future reference, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines about how to ask a well-received question.

Comment: Thank you Anshu , I appreciate your respectful approach to point out my rough spots

Comment: I really appreciate our respectful and constructive corrections of my shortcomings phakkert , thank you